# Show that $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ but $g^2\not\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
1/\sqrt{x} & \text{ for }0<|x|<1,\\0 & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Show that $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ but $g^2\not\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Wouldn't $g^2$ just be
$$g^2(x) =
\begin{cases}
1/x & \text{ for }0<|x|<1\\0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}?$$

I'm very confused and would appreciate any help.

Comment: That is right. So compute $\int_0^1 x^{-1/2} dx$ and $\int_0^1 x^{-1} dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. So what is $\|g^2\|_1$?

$$\|g^2\|_1 = \int_0^1 g(x)^2 dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} dx = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_\varepsilon^1 \frac{1}{x} dx = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+}  \left[\log(x)\right]_{\varepsilon}^1 = +\infty$$

Comment: There is no reason to take the $L^2$ norm since you already squared $g$.

Comment: Why do you use the $||\cdot||_2$?

Comment: Because I misread. Gonna edit.